# Vue snapshot tests work localy but fail on gitlab

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, gitlab-ci, snapshot, vue-test-utils

I am currently writing snapshot tests for mye Vue application. I am using vue-test-utils and jest to do this, and everything works wounderfully. The problem is when I try to push it to my repo, the test fails on gitlab with small issues like:

```
-             aria-haspopup="listbox"
+             aria-haspopup="true"
```

and

```
+         <!---->
```

Since I'm developing in Windows and gitlab runs some sort of Linux image, so I would guess this is where my problem stems from.
My question is, is there an easy fix for this?
About half of my snapshot tests run fine, so its not a setup issue.

Heres my gitlab-ci file.

```
build-job:
  stage: build
  image: node:14.16.1
  type: test
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run test
```